# Understanding a calculation step involving Mobius function

Tags: number-theory, mobius-function

For $ n=p_{ 1 }^{k_{1}}p_{2}^{k_{2}}......p_{r}^{k_{r}} $ where $p_{i}$'s are prime numbers, define $P = \prod _ { p _ { i } | n } [ \mu ( 1 ) + \frac { \mu ( p _ { i } ) } { p _ { i } } + \cdots + \frac { \mu ( p _ { i } ^ { k _ { i } } ) } { p _ { i } ^ { k _ { i } } } ]$

According to the book Elementary Number Theory by David M. Burton, $P$ can be simplified as

$\frac { \mu ( 1 ) \mu ( p _ { 1 } ^ { a _ { 1 } } ) \mu ( p _ { 2 } ^ { a _ { 2 } } ) \cdots \mu ( p _ { r } ^ { a _ { r } } ) } { p _ { 1 } ^ { a _ { 1 } } p _ { 2 } ^ { a _ { 2 } } \cdots p _ { r } ^ { a _ { r } } }$ for $0 \leq a _ { i } \leq k _ { i }$.

Can anyone help me to understand how to achieve this form?

Definition of $\mu$ :

$\mu ( n ) = \left\{ \begin{array} { l l } { 1 } & { \text { if } n = 1 } \\ { 0 } & { \text { if } p ^ { 2 } | n \text { for some prime } p } \\ { ( - 1 ) ^ { r } } & { \text { if } n = p _ { 1 } p _ { 2 } \cdots p _ { r } , \text { where } p _ { i } \text { are distinct primes } } \end{array} \right.$

Please help....

Comment: Since $\mu(p^m) = 0$ except when $m = 0, 1$,$$P = \prod_{ p_i\mid n} 1 - \frac 1{p_i}$$ and your other expression is very unclear. $P$ cannot be equal to all of those expressions for all of the various $0 \le a_i \le k_i$, because that expression has different values for different choices of the $a_i$ (for most of those choices, that value is $0$, but if we restrict all the $a_i$ to be either $0$ or $1$, we get some non-zero values). Given $n, P$ is a single number, not a multitude of numbers..

Comment: Exactly my point.
That's why I am not being able to understand. But it's written in a very authentic number theory book. So I am wondering if there is any other possibility that I am not being able to see !!!

Comment: So you are not the one who dropped the summation symbol?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a product of sums
$$\prod_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{k_i} u_{ij}$$
by repeated application of the distributive law, this becomes a sum of $\prod_{i=1}^n (k_i+1)$ terms. Each of these terms will be a product $\prod_{i=1}^n u_{ia_i}$ for some sequence of $n$ non-negative integers $a_i$ with $a_i \le k_i$ for all $i$. And for any such sequence $a_i$, the expanded expression will have the corresponding $\prod_{i=1}^n u_{ia_i}$ term. I.e.,

$$\prod_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{k_i} u_{ij} = \sum_{\{a_i\} \in \mathscr A} \prod_{i=1}^n u_{ia_i}, \quad \mathscr A = \{ \{a_i\} \subset \Bbb Z^{n}\mid \forall i, 0\le a_i \le k_i\}$$

This is how the second expression (with the missing summation symbol restored) was derived, with $u_{ij} = \dfrac{\mu(p_i^j)}{p_i^j}$.

There is an extraneous factor of $\mu(1)$ in the terms. Perhaps the author was including an $i=0$ factor of the original product which consisted of $\mu(1)$ only. But since this is just $1$, it doesn't matter.

As I noted in my comment, this is easily reducible by the properties of $\mu$. I don't know why the author has not already done so at this point. Presumably he makes that reduction later.